# infoBubble wrong positioned over marker

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infobubble

i have a google map with a single marker and a single infoBubble. The infobubble appears when clicking on the marker. The problem is that the infobubble appears right on the marker, not over it. See screenshots:

infoBubble is closed:
[image: infoBubble is closed]
infoBubble is open:
[image: infoBubble is open]
This is the code, i am using geocoder as i have only the named adress:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: results[0].geometry.location,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            //i am using simple InfoBubble initialization
            var infoBubble = new InfoBubble(
                {
                    map: map,
                    content: "<h2>"+name+"</h2><div>"+street+"</div><div>"+city+", "+zip+"</div>"
                });


            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
                infoBubble.open(map,marker);
            });

        }
    });
```

any clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

ommit the `map`-option when creating the infoBubble.

Answer (score 0):

I find this example very handy [http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html][1], try below snippet.

```
var map, infoBubble;
      function init() {
        var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-35.397, 150.644);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: mapCenter,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(-35, 150),
          draggable: true
        });

        infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
          maxWidth: 300
        });

        infoBubble.open(map, marker);

        infoBubble.setContent('This is a sample content') //Please set your content here.

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          if (!infoBubble.isOpen()) {
            infoBubble.open(map, marker);
          }
          });

      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
}


  [1]: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html
```